# Rudra is an archer right from the Rig Veda - was his bow called "Pinaka" in the Rig Veda?

Tags: shiva, pinaka

Did Rudra have a named bow in Rig Veda or did Rudra/Siva acquire Pinaka in a later scripture?

Answer (score 6):

Sri Rudra the supreme God is the greatest archer mentioned in the Vedas. The Rig Veda does not give us the name of his bow. But in the Yajurveda, he is called the bearer of Pinaka (TS.1.8.6) and also we ask Rudra to keep the Pianka bow away from us or wear it as an ornament (TS.4.5.10).

प॒र॒मे वृ॒क्ष आयु॑धन्नि॒धाय॒ कृत्तिं॒-वँसा॑न॒ **आच॑र॒ पिना॑कं॒ बिभ्र॒दाग॑हि** ।

> Placing down your weapon on the highest tree, clad in your tiger-skin,
> come and approach us bearing the Pināka (as an ornament)
>
> *TS.4.5.10*

[image]

Another instance:

ए॒ष ते॑ रुद्र भा॒गस्त-ञ्जु॑षस्व॒ तेना॑व॒सेन॑ प॒रो मूज॑व॒तो-ऽती॒ह्य व॑ततधन्वा॒ **पिना॑कहस्तः॒** कृत्ति॑वासाः

> This is thy portion, O Rudra; rejoice in it; with it for food, do thou
> go away beyond the Mujavants. With unstrung bow, thy bow in thy hand,
> clad in skins.
>
> *TS.1.8.6.11*

Hope it helps.